How to automatically extract all variables from a complete code block and place them into a list?
In the code for drawing 3D geometric figures, there are usually several variables related to points. How can one automatically extract all these variables from the complete drawing code and form them into a list?
Clear["Global`*"];
a={0,0,0};
b={2,0,0};
d=2 {Cos[\[Pi]/3],Sin[\[Pi]/3],0};
c=b+d;
p={x,y,z};
p=SolveValues[{(p-a) . (a-c)==0,Cross[p-a,p-c] . Cross[p-b,p-d]==0,Norm[p-a]==2,z>0},{x,y,z}]//First
m=Mean[{p,b}];
o=Mean[{a,b,c,d}];
labels={Text[Style[P,12,FontFamily->"Times"],p,{-1,-1}],Text[Style[A,12,FontFamily->"Times"],a,{1,1}],Text[Style[B,12,FontFamily->"Times"],b,{1,1}],Text[Style[C,12,FontFamily->"Times"],c,{-2,0}],Text[Style[D,12,FontFamily->"Times"],d,{3,0}],Text[Style[M,12,FontFamily->"Times"],m,{-1,-2}],Text[Style[O,12,FontFamily->"Times"],o,{0,1}]};
Graphics3D[{Thick,Line[{p,a,b}],Line[{p,b,c,p}],Line[{a,m,c}],Dashed,Line[{a,c}],Line[{b,d}],Line[{d,p}],Line[{d,a}],Line[{d,c}],labels},Boxed->False,ViewPoint->{-.9,-3,1.28}]

Given a specific piece of code for drawing 3D geometric figures, how can one extract all the variables from this code and get them in a list format?
list = {a, b, c, d, p, m, o}


Depends on what you mean by variables. Cases[Hold@code, s_Symbol /; Context[s] === "Global", Infinity]might work on the above. OrContext[Unevaluated@s]`, which is safer.

And to continue @MichaelE2's idea: You can obtain code by something like code = MakeExpression[NotebookRead[Cells[][[1]]]] (assuming your cell is the first one in your notebook). Although you should really think of some better approach for solving your problem instead of this hackery with extracting variables ...

It's still not clear what you mean by "variables related to points." Do you mean the variables that appear inside Graphics3D[] AND inside a graphics primitive, ignoring inside graphics directives and options and ignoring dependencies like x, y, z. That is, only literal "variables" that appear in the last line? What about coordinates that determine the location of Inset/Text, which don't matter in this example? What about other variables that appear in Text but are not coordinates? The title of this question is conflict with this interpertation "complete code" vs Graphics3D expression

It's not clear what the "input" of the problem is. Are you going to type/copy all the code into an argument for a function? Is the input a notebook or a cell in a notebook as @Domen posits? Is the problem only about this specific code above or do you have lots of examples that need this odd processing? If specific, then the answer has been given in the last line of the post above, and solve in probably the easiest and quickest way.

Some variables in some code might represent primitives themselves instead of points. line1 = Line[{a,b}]; Graphics[{line1}]. What should be the output?

This worksish, but gives all the new symbols, not only the list you want (missed that first time around), but at the expense of overwriting anything that conflicts with the variables in the code. EDIT: oh I think this basically does what you seek with the added search for OwnValues:
Remove["dummyContextForNames`*"];
Begin["dummyContextForNames`"];
namesnow = {};
$NewSymbol = AppendTo[namesnow, #1] &;
(*begin code*)
a = {0, 0, 0};
b = {2, 0, 0};
d = 2 {Cos[\[Pi]/3], Sin[\[Pi]/3], 0};
c = b + d;
p = {x, y, z};
p = SolveValues[{(p - a) . (a - c) == 0, 
     Cross[p - a, p - c] . Cross[p - b, p - d] == 0, Norm[p - a] == 2,
      z > 0}, {x, y, z}] // First;
m = Mean[{p, b}];
o = Mean[{a, b, c, d}];
labels = {Text[Style[P, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], p, {-1, -1}], 
   Text[Style[A, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], a, {1, 1}], 
   Text[Style[B, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b, {1, 1}], 
   Text[Style[C, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], c, {-2, 0}], 
   Text[Style[D, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], d, {3, 0}], 
   Text[Style[M, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], m, {-1, -2}], 
   Text[Style[O, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], o, {0, 1}]};
Graphics3D[{Thick, Line[{p, a, b}], Line[{p, b, c, p}], 
  Line[{a, m, c}], Dashed, Line[{a, c}], Line[{b, d}], Line[{d, p}], 
  Line[{d, a}], Line[{d, c}], labels}, Boxed -> False, 
 ViewPoint -> {-.9, -3, 1.28}]
(*end code*)
$NewSymbol =.;
Select[namesnow, Length[OwnValues[#]] > 0 &] 
(*{"a", "b", "d", "c", "p", "m", "o", "labels"}*)
End[]

A slightly shorter method is to skip the logging with $NewSymbol and just query the context
Remove["dummyContextForNames`*"];
Begin["dummyContextForNames`"];
(*startcode*)

(*end code*)
Names["dummyContextForNames`*"](*{"a", "A", "b", "B", "c",\
 "d", "labels", "m", "M", "o", "p", "P", "x", "y", "z"}*)
End[]

The difference is the first method gives them in order of first appearance, which might be handy.

If a symbol has been created in another context in the context path, it won't be created in the dummy context. (Put, say, a; before the first line and execute.) Maybe use BeginPackage?

It would relatively easy to do if  would be possible to suppress the execution of Graphics in input.
So replace Graphics by Inactive[Graphics] and define
 Clear["Global`*"];
  SetAttributes[t, HoldAll]

  t[expr_] := HoldComplete[expr]

 pp = t[{
   a = {0, 0, 0};
   b = {2, 0, 0};
   d = 2 {Cos[\[Pi]/3], Sin[\[Pi]/3], 0};
   ...
   Inactive[Graphics3D][{Thick, Line[{p, a, b}], Line[{p, b, c, p}], 
     Line[{a, m, c}], Dashed, Line[{a, c}], Line[{b, d}], 
     Line[{d, p}], Line[{d, a}], Line[{d, c}], labels}, 
    Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {-.9, -3, 1.28}];}]

Find all Symbol's and convert them to strings
 (s1 = Sort@Union@Flatten@
      Cases[pp, x_Symbol :>  ToString[Unevaluated[x]], \[Infinity]]]]) // 
       TableForm

Get the list of all "Global`*"
 globals = Names["Global`*"]

 Out={"a", "A", "b", "B", "c", "d", "expr", "globals", "labels", "m", "M", \
      "o", "p", "P", "pp", "res", "s1", "t", "x", "y", "z"}

and find the
Symbol /@ Intersection[s1, globals]

 {a, A, b, B, c, d, labels, m, M, o, p, P, x, y, z}


I will point out for others that Graphics[] and Graphics3D[] don't really execute or evaluate to a new value. MakeBoxes[] converts the expression to boxes upon output, which are then interpreted and typeset by the Front End as graphics. Inactive[Graphics3D][..] would prevent MakeBoxes[] from converting it to a Graphics3DBox[] and being displayed as graphics, but since it is not output in the code above, Inactive[Graphics3D] has no significant effect. This is essentially the same idea as in my comment from yesterday, both of which cull more variables than the OP desires.
